# insert values into SQL database using servlet

Tags: java, oracle

Whenever I'm running this code, I'm getting a `not enough values`. What could be going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Base extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws 
IOException,ServletException
    {
        String eid=req.getParameter("t1");
        String name=req.getParameter("t2");
        int sal=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("t3"));
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        try
        {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","intelinside" );
              stmt=con.createStatement();
              int i = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values('"+eid+"''"+name+"''"+sal+"')");
              if(i>0)
                out.println("Inserted Successfully");
              else
                out.println("Insert Unsuccessful");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          out.println(e);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: not enough values error is showing up.

Comment: so would we magically know what the error is ?? update your question with the error

Comment: you should use PreparedStatement... And delegate your database logic to a DAO class. It is better testable.

Answer (score 3):

your sql is wrong:

```
int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values('"+eid+"''"+name+"''"+sal+"')");
```

where is the `,` between the columns?

change it to this:

```
int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values('"+eid+"','"+name+"','"+sal+"')");
```

btw. use `PreparedStatement`
your way is a pretty good example for SQL-Injection.

Comment: Ohh such a stupid mistake thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You missed putting *commas* between your column values.

```
int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values('"+eid+"','"+name+"','"+sal+"')");
```

But, I suggest using a ***PreparedStatement*** instead. Your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks otherwise. Specially, because you're fetching the user input over the web as request parameters without any validation.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO emp VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

pstmt.setString(1, eid);
pstmt.setString(2, name);
pstmt.setString(3, sal);

int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commas in your values() clause. Come on, be more careful.

Comment: Be more careful? No. It is the best way to learn anything.

Comment: Ohh such a stupid mistake thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commas in between column values. As a better approach you should use column names and accordingly the column values. In future if table structure changes- like a new column is added is table, your query will start to fail.

```
"insert into emp(employyeId, empName, empSalary) values('"+eid+"','"+name+"','"+sal+"')"
```

Here you are giving tight mapping between column names and corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this line for update.

int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into employee values('"+eid+"','"+name+"',"+sal+")");

Hope it will work for you.